# Cuts h1 tag when outputting via function.php

Tags: wordpress, tags

This is the situation, I need to display the title h1 tag name on tag pages.
I add in function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'bbloomer_loop_tag' );
function bbloomer_loop_tag() {
 
if ( is_product_tag() ) {
    
woocommerce_page_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
} 
else {
echo '';
}
 
}
```

Outputs the tag title but no tags ', '

How to correctly output the title tags through function.php so that they are in the wrapper ', ' ?

Answer (score 0):

`woocommerce_page_title` accepts only one parameter `$echo`.

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Awoocommerce%2Fwoocommerce%20woocommerce_page_title&type=code

You have no control over the output tags as they are output inline in the template. You have to either override the Archive Product template (https://woo.com/document/template-structure/) or, as a quick hack would be to suppress it via the filter, and output the HTML you but using the `woocommerce_archive_description` hook as to output it in the right place within the `<header>` markup.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', '__return_false' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', function() {
    printf( '<h1 class="page-title">%s</h1>', woocommerce_page_title() );
} );
```